# templatecachequeries entries with of 157.000 characters in query column

Tags: craft3, cache, mysql

after enableling querycaching in craft3 I found rows in templatecachequeries with big amount of characters in the query field. I decoded it with base64 and got this as the largest entry:

```
query_length: 157036

query_decoded:
O:28:"craft\elements\db\EntryQuery":71:{s:8:"editable";b:0;s:9:"sectionId";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"7";}s:6:"typeId";N;s:8:"authorId";N;s:13:"authorGroupId";N;s:8:"postDate";N;s:6:"before";N;s:5:"after";N;s:10:"expiryDate";N;s:17:" 

query: TzoyODoiY3JhZnRcZWxlbWVudHNcZGJcRW...(+157.000)
```

my sql query:

```
select length(query) as query_length , FROM_BASE64(query) as query_decoded, query
from craft_templatecachequeries
order by query_length desc
```

why does the unencoded query with a size of 221 characters get encoded to a size of 157036 characters?

Answer (score 1):

turns out it was an error in my TablePlus, it truncated the decoded_query to 221 characters.